# How to add aliases to on_message command?

Tags: python, command, discord.py

So I made this help command section, where if the user types %help moderation, it lists the moderation commands. But I want to have aliases or disable case sensitivity.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('%help moderation'):
      await message.channel.send("%ban, %kick, %purge <limit>, %warn, %membercount, %botcount")
```

Then, this is the help command I actually have as an embed:

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Commands", 
    description="Here are all the commands to use:", color=0x0618C1)
    embed.add_field(name="Moderation", value="Moderation Commands", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Fun", value="General Fun Commands", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Random", value="Commands that do random things", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to add extra options (arguments) to the help command/make it not case sensitive?

Comment: Well first of all, I’m getting a error saying that embed isn’t classified, and yes, I’m looking for a way to add arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You should decide if you want to use the `on_message` event or the commands extension. Using `on_message` [will conflict with command processing if you don't configure it correctly](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=on_message#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working).
If you don't have a good reason to use `on_message` I suggest sticking with the commands extension and read up on the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) to define parameters.

If you want to disable case sensitivity, you can do so when initializing the Bot object and if you want to provide a custom help command it's a good idea to disable the one built in.

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%',
                   case_insensitive=True, # Disable command case sensitivity
                   help_command=None) # Disable built in help command
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the command framework that discord.py provide it to you it more easier to work with it

just put in the `@client.command()` a name like `name="your command name"` and than a array like this `aliases=['first','second']`

so your code will be like this

```
@client.command(name="your command name" , aliases=['first','second'])
async def def_name(ctx):
     #command
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a better way of doing all of this. You can use:

```
@client.group(invoke_without_command = True) # the invoke_without_command = True states that %help will be executed without a subcommand like %help moderation.
async def help(ctx):
    # your code here
```

instead of `client.command()` to create a so called command group, which allows you to use a command with extensions. In order to put in a subcommand, in your case "moderation", you need to use:

```
@help.command()
async def moderation(ctx):
    # whatever should happen if someone types in "%help moderation".
```

This is a pretty cool feature in discord.py, which prevents you from using on_message events every time.

This is what your code would look like in the end:

```
@client.group()
async def help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Commands", 
    description="Here are all the commands to use:", color=0x0618C1)
    embed.add_field(name="Moderation", value="Moderation Commands", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Fun", value="General Fun Commands", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Random", value="Commands that do random things", 
    inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@help.command()
async def moderation(ctx):
    await ctx.send("%ban, %kick, %purge <limit>, %warn, %membercount, %botcount")
```

So back to your question: You can now add aliases to the subcommand by putting "aliases" as a parameter into the @help.command() like this:

```
@help.command(aliases = ["first", "second", "third"])
```